# angular page data sort itself when click anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, angular, mouseevent, angular8

`Mouse Click` anywhere on the page, even blank spot, the data array on the page just resort itself.

I know that `click` might trigger view change if `impure` pipe is set but I didn't use any.

So I am really baffled because my development testing is OK. Only the production build has this weird behavior.

I use `angular 8`. The data on the page is array down from rest endpoint. I simply `for` loop it like all other pages does. This page is just having a big object as the response and containing 3 big arrays. And I make 3 different list on the page. Each list is also a `input` for a sub component. Display after sorting.

I know JS `sort` does not copy. But why only on production build?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the pipe which is used to filter the lists. That's it.

But I couldn't explain the cause of it.

The pipe is doing a filter. It filters the list based on some ids which belongs to the data.

A checkbox will trigger the filtering which is `*ngIf` on the tables row in the template.